# Using useState of complex object not working as expected in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, react-hooks, use-state

I have a function component and I am declaring a `useState` for a complex object like this:

```
    const [order, setOrder] = useState<IMasterState>({
        DataInterface: null,
        ErrorMsg: "",
        IsRetrieving: true,
        RetrievingMsg: "Fetching your order status..."
    });
```

I now try to set the state of the `order` by calling `setOrder` in a `useEffect` like this:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        (async function() {
            let dh = new DataInterface("some string");
            let errMsg = "";
            
            // Get the sales order.
            try
            {
                await dh.FetchOrder();
            }
            catch(error: any)
            {
                errMsg = error;
            };
            
            setOrder(salesOrder => ({...salesOrder, IsRetrieving: false, ErrorMsg: errMsg, DataInterface: dh}));
        })();
    }, []);
```

As is, this seems to work fine. However, I have a `setInterval` object that changes the screen message while `order.IsRetrieving` is `true`:

```
    const [fetchCheckerCounter, setFetchCheckerCount] = useState<number>(0);

    const statusFetcherWatcher = setInterval(() => {
        if (order.IsRetrieving)
        {
            if (fetchCheckerCounter === 1)
            {
                setOrder(salesOrder => ({...salesOrder, RetrievingMsg: "This can take a few seconds..."}));
            }
            else if (fetchCheckerCounter === 2)
            {
                setOrder(salesOrder => ({...salesOrder, RetrievingMsg: "Almost there!.."}));
            }

            setFetchCheckerCount(fetchCheckerCounter + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            // Remove timer.
            clearInterval(statusFetcherWatcher);
        }
    }, 7000);
```

The issue is that `order.IsRetrieving` is always `true` for that code block, even though it does change to `false`, and my website changes to reflect that, even showing the data from `dh.FetchOrder()`. That means my timer goes on an infinite loop in the background.

So am I setting the state of `order` correctly? It's incredibly difficult to find a definite answer on the net, since all the answers are invariably about adding a new item to an array.

Comment: don't call `setInterval()` during the render phase, that's the first problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issues

1. You are setting the interval as an unintentional side-effect in the function body.
2. You have closed over the initial `order.isRetreiving` state value in the interval callback.

## Solution

Use a mounting `useEffect` to start the interval and use a React ref to cache the state value when it updates so the current value can be accessed in asynchronous callbacks.

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState<IMasterState>({
  DataInterface: null,
  ErrorMsg: "",
  IsRetrieving: true,
  RetrievingMsg: "Fetching your order status..."
});

const orderRef = useRef(order);

useEffect(() => {
  orderRef.current = order;
}, [order]);

useEffect(() => {
  const statusFetcherWatcher = setInterval(() => {
    if (orderRef.current.IsRetrieving) {
      if (fetchCheckerCounter === 1) {
        setOrder(salesOrder => ({
          ...salesOrder,
          RetrievingMsg: "This can take a few seconds...",
        }));
      } else if (fetchCheckerCounter === 2) {
        setOrder(salesOrder => ({
          ...salesOrder,
          RetrievingMsg: "Almost there!..",
        }));
      }

      setFetchCheckerCount(counter => counter + 1);
    } else {
      // Remove timer.
      clearInterval(statusFetcherWatcher);
    }
  }, 7000);

  return () => clearInterval(statusFetcherWatcher);
}, []);
```